# What does the permission LENSVIEW_BROADCAST do?

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions

I found a permission in Google Maps' manifest file and was wondering what it does:

**com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.permission.LENSVIEW_BROADCAST**

Any ideas?

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom permission related to using Google Lens.